# How to detect protected cells in Excel file using Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, nlp, openpyxl

Given that an Excel file contains some cells protected with passwords, I want to detect these protected cells to choose whether to include them in the inputs or skip them.

I have tried `pandas`

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

and `openpyxl`

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
# B4 is a protected cell with a specific password so I cannot change its value in
# the Excel file without the password
print(sheet['B4'].value)
>> 8
sheet['B4'].value = 7
print(sheet['B4'].value)
>> 7
```

However, the protected cells are read normally like other unprotected cells and could be easily changed.

So the question is, how could I detect these protected cells?

For example, is there any way to read the attributes of the Excel file that indicate if the cell is protected or not?

Comment: This is covered in the documentation: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html

Comment: @CharlieClark Thank you for your help. Do you mean this piece of code `protection = Protection(locked=True, hidden=False)`, and specifically the attribute `locked=True`?

Comment: Just set `cell.protection = None`

Comment: @CharlieClark Why should I do that? I wanted to check if the cell is protected or not. This was done using `sheet['B4'].protection.locked` which evaluates to `True` or `False` to indicate whether the cell is protected or not. So what is the usefulness of setting `cell.protection = None` in my situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With openpyxl, you can detect the locked or hidden status of each cell with its `protection` attribute, e.g.:

```
>>> sheet['B4'].protection.locked
True
>>> sheet['B4'].protection.hidden
False
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. That solved my problem.

Comment: But excuse me, how do you know such information, and Where could I find such information? because I searched but didn't find a solution. And that's why I asked here. I want to benefit from your experience and from your way of learning.

Comment: Sometimes you just need to explore. In a Python interpreter, save a cell like ```c = sheet['B4']``` and then look at the list of methods and attributes with ```dir(c)```, dir(c.protection)``` etc., to see what's available.

Comment: This is a great piece of information. Yes, exploration is part of the learning process. Thank you so much.